# custom currency filter to the input field in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to  formatting the value in to indian currency type using angularjs.
for example, **454565 to 4,54,565.00**

I have input field like this:

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="item.cost />
```

Comment: customize the price to what ? provide more info

Comment: for exmaple convert value from 454565 to 4,54,565.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function FormatMyNumber(yourNumber) {
    // Limit to two decimal places 
    yourNumber = parseFloat(yourNumber).toFixed(2);
    //Seperates the components of the number
    var n = yourNumber.toString().split(".");
    //Comma-fies the first part
    n[0] = n[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    //Combines the two sections
    return n.join(".");
}

FormatMyNumber(454565); //yields 454,565.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive for it as follows

HTML

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      {{amount}}
      <input format-to-currency amount="amount">
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.ampunt = 2;
    })
    .directive('formatToCurrency', function($filter) {
      return {
        scope: {
          amount: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));

          el.bind('focus', function() {
            el.val(scope.amount);
          });

          el.bind('input', function() {
            scope.amount = el.val();
            scope.$apply();
          });

          el.bind('blur', function() {
            el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount));
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Link http://jsfiddle.net/moL8ztrw/6/